# How do i one hot encode sentences and phrases in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to one-hot encode a DataFrame full of strings and phrases. The DataFrame has two columns, "answer_text" and "context".

I want to one-hot encode each string in the two columns. Because "answer_text" is derived from whatever's in the "context" column, I kind of want both columns to be encoded with the same vocabulary so that I can feed my neural network questions that it has not seen and generate answers from the parts of the text that it has read.
For this task, I initally turned to scikit-learn's MultiLabelBinarizer:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
contextTotal = pd.concat((trainingData["context"],devData["context"]))
print("Gathered content")
contextBinarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
contextBinarizer.fit(contextTotal.str.split(" "))
print(contextBinarizer.classes_) # Why is this giving me an array of arrays?
test = contextBinarizer.inverse_transform(contextBinarizer.transform(pd.Series([["Saint","Bernadette"]])))
print("Test",test)
print("Content binarizer fit.")
```

However, for the answer_text column, I want to be able to reconstruct the original string. For example, any method I test using the string "Saint Bernadette Soubirous" should, when reversed, give me the string "Saint Bernadette Soubirous" - something that does not happen when I use the MultiLabelBinarizer.

Edit: I am also open to using TensorFlow, Keras, and Pandas.

Here's [the dataset](https://github.com/moonman239/Capstone-project/blob/master/training_data.csv).

Comment: It looks like I can use NLTK's word_tokenizer, combined with df[column_name].apply(pd.Series), then process the result with pd.DataFrame. This method appears to preserve order - but caveat emptor, this is an implementation detail.

Comment: Can't you use [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) with an option binary=True?

Comment: @ArtemTrunov: The problem with that approach is that for my neural network, order matters. I need, for example, a way to encode "The quick brown fox" differently than "The brown quick fox". (Although, I suppose I could try with the CountVectorizer)

Comment: I think you could also can look at ngramms then. or use LSTM in case of NN

Comment: @ArtemTrunov: Hi Artem - I don't feel that ngrams would help - at least not for the answer_text column. I want to preserve the order of the words in a sentence - please see my edit above for more information.